# Weird mesh appearing on certain frames

Tags: rendering, mesh, error, lines

I created a character animation, in which weird lines appear - but only in the render, and only in certain frames.
It´s always the same frames, but, depending on the frame, those lines appear or disappear stronger or lighter.

[image]

Comment: Could it be that you're using Cycles as render engine with motion blur enabled and auto smooth on the mesh? This is known to cause artifacts. Motion blur with auto smooth is currently not properly supported. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/render_settings/motion_blur.html#limitations

Comment: Thanks a lot! You just saved my life... :)